Approximation/Trick for rendering wormholes as simple objects
Is there a know trick/approximation used to render a simple wormhole effect such as this one:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dccRr
I was thinking of some formula given:

An outer effect radius, Ro
The actual size of the wormhole: Ri
The view vector to a point on the outer effect radius circle
The normal of a point on the outer effect radius circle

( Normal on a circle and position are interchangeable )
would give:

Fate of a light ray: curved back, got stuck or went through the wormhole
The exit vector at the outer effect radius circle
The exit normal at the outer effect radius circle


This would allow you to render a wormhole as a spherical mesh which samples from two HDRI/spherical maps. Whilst it wouldn't reflect dynamic changes in a scene it is good enough.
The math behind calculating geodesics in order to calculate the light ray paths goes above my head and there likely isn't a closed form solution, which is why I'm interested in tricks/approximations.
